# How to disable safe area layout guide for scrollview programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I have view, created programmatically. How i can disable scrollView safe area layout guide programmatically?

Comment: You can't disable the safe area as it's part of UIViewController, but you don't have to use it if you don't want to.  Just use other margin/anchors for your design.  However if you want to put the app in the App Store you probably should use it!

Comment: @flanker What does putting an app in App Store have to do with not using a certain layout guide?

Comment: @maddy I've known of apps not get approved for not supporting the SALG and screwing up the notch.  I've got a feeling (could be wrong) that it was made a requirement when the X came out?  Either way, not designing for the notch (assuming iPhone, of course) wouldn't be a good pattern for a commercial app.